# cached request can't get the new header

Tags: browser, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm facing a cache issue from a client. I've already added a new header Cache-Control to the response but it still keeps caching. I tried it with the user cached and with a disabled cache browser

With disabled cache browser:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate  
Pragma: no-cache  
Content-Type: text/html  
Expires: 0  
Last-Modified: Thu, 05 Oct 2023 11:41:12 GMT  
ETag: "9aa213d780f7d91:0"  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization  
Date: Thu, 05 Oct 2023 11:42:55 GMT  
Content-Length: 9136
```

With user cached:

```
Content-Type: text/html  
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Sep 2023 08:42:16 GMT  
ETag: "0a41afe7f1d91:0"  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization  
Date: Thu, 05 Oct 2023 11:29:29 GMT  
Content-Length: 9128
```

What should I do for this cached user?